# AngularJS: ng-mouseOver on touch screens

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have the following:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3AYRXUfbaT1VebN3J7uB?p=preview)

[image]

On mouse over anyone of the black Cubes it's number is passed to the red Cube

but it doesn't work for touch screens.

i need the user to be able to move his finger from cube to cube (without picking his finger up). and every time his finger touches a black cube, to update the red cubes number.

P.B: the cubes size and position will be generated dynamically.

My code:

```
<div class="main" ng-mouseover="setSelected(1)">
     <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="num">1</div>
     </div>
 </div>


<div class="main" ng-mouseover="setSelected(2)">
     <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="num">2</div>
     </div>
 </div>


<div class="main" ng-mouseover="setSelected(3)">
     <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="num">3</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

---

```
<div class="selected" style="">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
       <div class="num">Selected</div>
       <BR />
       <div class="num">{{selected}}</div>
   </div>
</div>



var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        $scope.selected = '00';


        $scope.setSelected = function(num){
        $scope.selected = num;
      }
  });
```

Thank's

Avi

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem, but I don't think you want to use a `MouseOver`.

Problem with touch devices is there is no mouse so it can never over. You only have touch down and mouse move events.

Here's what I would do:

1. Add `ng-mouseDown` and `ng-mouseUp` to the parent container of those blocks. Then record on the scope whether or not the mouse is down:

   ```
   <div ng-init="mouse={down:false}" ng-mouseDown="mouse.down=true" ng-mouseUp="mouse.down=false" > ... </div>
   ```

   2. Add and `ng-mouseEnter` to each one of those elements. Then call your function in the scope and check to see if the mouse is down. If so, fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create your own, using `ngTouch`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

If you look at the `$swipe` service, you can create a directive which is able to make use of when users begin and end swipe actions, gaining access to things like coordinates.